# VBA/Excel - Group by value in table and send e-mail

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes

I have a large list where I have different companies and organisations. My current VBA codes iterates through each table row, and send out an e-mail for each line.

**However**, what I need to achieve is that there might be companies which have the same parent organisation - in this case, I don't want to send out an e-mail *for each* company, but would rather send out **one** e-mail to the organisation, including all the associated companies.

I have tried to illustrate it in below table.

[image]

So for record #1, I would just send out an e-mail as always. However for [2-3], I would like to send out **one** e-mail, which includes company name 2 and 3.
Same goes for record [4-6], which should also send out **one** e-mail, but include company name #4, #5 and #6.

**Example:**

Hi **Organisation B**

Please check below companies in your organisation:

- Company 2
- Company 3

**My current code:**
Below is my current code, which iterates through all table rows and send out mails:

```
 'Count table rows
 Set tbl = oWorksheet.ListObjects("DataTable")
 TableRows = tbl.ListRows.Count
 TableRows = TableRows + 1 'Skips the header
 iRow = 2 'Skip the header

 Do While iRow <= TableRows
       Set oNotesMail = oMailDB.CreateDocument
       oNotesMail.Form = "Memo"
       oNotesMail.SendTo = oWorksheet.Cells(iRow, 5).Value
       oNotesMail.Subject = "Company check"
       oNotesMail.Body = "Hi " & oWorksheet.Cells(iRow, 2) & "Please check"
       oNotesMail.SaveMessageOnSend = True
       oNotesMail.PostedDate = Now()
       oNotesMail.Send 0, oWorksheet.Cells(iRow, 5).Value
       Set oNotesMail = Nothing
    Loop
```

So above code send out an email (in Lotus Notes) for each line.

How can I achieve my example above?

**Please note**

- The table will always be sorted by 'Organisation' - hopefully this will help when the code is iterating through the rows.

Comment: You can use `Dictionary` object in VBA to create a list of unique Organizations and then compose emails based on it.